# Firebase realtime-db access with IAM service account on frontend

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I can't seem to find anywhere on how to access my realtime-db with service account from front-end. I need to make a small standalone web app that can interact with my realtime-db and change some resources that are restricted to authenticated users (and locked to his uid)

```
{
    "rules": {
        "users": {
            "$uid": {
                ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
                ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can do it in node.js with firebase-admin library, but I need a way to do this on client side only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to authenticate with an IAM account from the Firebase client SDKs. If this is a requirement for your app, you could build it as a custom authentication provider.

In that scenario you implement the client-side to determine the IAM user, send that information to your own server (or Cloud Functions that you write) to [generate a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens). The  [client then uses the custom token to sign in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth).

Comment: Thank You! After I while I figured out that much. At the end I created a regular application user, and added special rules for his ID in storage access settings.